# Detecting initial device orientation on iOS in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, uiinterfaceorientation

I know how to [detect device orientation change](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/SafariDOMAdditions/Reference/DeviceOrientationEventClassRef/DeviceOrientationEvent/DeviceOrientationEvent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010526) on iOS in Safari, but I cannot fathom out how to detect initial orientation when my page loads.

It is simple to detect if the device is in portrait or landscape mode - just divide window width with window height and compare result with 1. But I don't see a way to tell portrait from flipped and landscape left from landscape right. Is there a way to do it?

(Why do I need it? Because accelerometer data doesn't flip together with screen when a device is turned on its head. The code must therefore know the current orientation to correctly process accelerometer data.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check window.orientation on page load.