# is device orientation enabled javascript html5

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, orientation

I need to find out whether device orientation is locked on iPhone or Android devices.

I can find a way to find out if device orientation is ***supported*** but that won't help me when I want to display a message telling the user that my html5 web page needs rototion to landscape and that his device is locked...

Comment: The solution is to check orientation on page load. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152103/detecting-initial-device-orientation-on-ios-in-safari

Comment: And why is this a solution? Whatever the initial orientation, I still don't know whetrher rotation is locked or enabled...

Answer (score 0):

Its only a partial solution. Sorry.

I would check device window.orientation on page load, if its not landscape, display message to user to change orientation and turn off orientation lock.

Then listen for "devicemotion" event which should fire even if orientation is locked. Then on "devicemotion" check window.orientation again,  If window.orientation is landscape then dismiss message.

devicemotion
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/devicemotion